# How do you solve $f'(x) = f(f(x))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

A friend told me to solve the following differential equation:

$$f'(x)=f(f(x))$$

I have no idea how to solve this! This doesn't seem to be an ordinary differential equation and I can't even solve this numerically!

I think my friend is trolling me.

Comment: The constant function f(x) = 0 works....

Comment: Assume $f$ holomorphic and $f(0)=0$, say $0$ is a root of order $k$. Then $f(f(x))$ has a root of order $2k$ and $f'$ has a root of order $k-1$. Oops.

Comment: suppose $f(x)=x^n$ can satisfy this equation. Then $n-1=n^2.$ There are two complex solutions for this equation. I don't no they can be acceptable as an answers. But nothing seems like wrong.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The constant function $f(x) = 0$ cannot have a 'root of order $k$'. It has a zero at each $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, but none of its zeros is of finite order since $f(\alpha) = f^{\prime}(\alpha) = f^{\prime \prime}(\alpha) = \cdots = 0$.

Comment: @davincisghost Yes, after your original comment I was of course looking for *nontrivial* holomorphic solutions. In a way $\infty$ is a solution of $2k=k-1$ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has been asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111066/is-there-any-techniques-for-solving-a-differential-equation-including-iterated-f), this answer is migrated from there: -

There are two closed form solutions:

$$\displaystyle f_1(x) = e^{\frac{\pi}{3} (-1)^{1/6}} x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
$$\displaystyle f_2(x) = e^{\frac{\pi}{3} (-1)^{11/6}} x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

The solution technique can be found in [this paper](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/math/akca/papers/cheng.pdf).

For a general case, solution of the equation

$$f'(z)=f^{[m]}(z)$$

has the form

$$f(z)=\beta z^\gamma$$

where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ should be obtained from the system

$$\gamma^m=\gamma-1$$
$$\beta^{\gamma^{m-1}+...+\gamma}=\gamma$$

In your case $m=2$.

Note: I merely brought this to your attention, all credit should go to Anixx on MO.