# Differential equation related to Golomb's sequence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While studying [Golomb's sequence](https://oeis.org/A001462), the following differential equation arouse:
$$
f(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}
$$
I don't know much about differential equations so I am a bit clueless. Is there a way to solve it nicely?

Edit:

With the link provided by Michael Galuza, I could find a function which satisfies the given equation, namely:
$$
f(x)=\varphi^{2-\varphi}x^{\varphi-1}
$$
Where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the golden ratio. However, I did not succeed in proving that this is the only one. Is this feasible?

Comment: Very close to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916967/how-do-you-solve-fx-ffx)

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y =f(x)$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)$ so that the D.E. becomes $f(y)=\frac{dx}{dy}$ so $f(y)dy=dx$.

We have two ways:

- The D.E. is separable, integrating both sides we get $\int {f(y)dy=x+c}$
- The equation $dx-f(y)dy=0$ is exact since $M(x,y)=1$ and $N(x,y)=-f(y)$ we have $M_y=0$ and $N_x=0$.

Let $\Phi(x,y)$ be a differentiable function such that $\Phi_x=1$ $ \Rightarrow $ $\Phi(x,y)=x+h(y)$. On the other hand, $\Phi_y=N(x,y)$ so that $h'(y) = -f(y)$ which gives that $h(y)=-\int{f(y)dy}+C$.

Hence, $\Phi(x,y)=x-\int{f(y)dy}+C$.