# About an asymptote of Golomb's sequence and an asymptote of a sequence in general

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387956/differential-equation-related-to-golombs-sequence), I asked for the solutions to the differential equation $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ because I think that a solution to this equation is related to [Golomb's sequence](https://oeis.org/A001462). Let me explain, why:

In [Golomb's sequence](https://oeis.org/A001462), $a_k$ is the number of times that $k$ appears in the sequence, $a_1=1$ and $a_k$ being the smallest number satisfying this condition greater than or equal to $a_{k-1}$. It can be deduced fairly easy, that for:
$$
k=\sum_{r=1}^n a_r
$$
$k$ is the greatest integer with $a_k=n$. In order to find an asymptote, I thought of considering the function $f(k)=a_k \space\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. With the above mentioned statement, we can deduce that:
$$
f\left(\sum_{r=1}^n f(r)\right)=n
$$
Its pretty intuitive, that $f$ is related to the function $\overset{\sim}{f}$ which satisfies the similar condition
$$
\overset{\sim}{f}\left(\int_{0}^{x}\overset{\sim}{f}(z)dz\right)=x
$$
Which can be found by considering the solutions to $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$. It seems indeed to be the case, that for $\overset{\sim}{f}(x)=\varphi^{2-\varphi}x^{\varphi-1}$ ($\varphi$ is the golden ratio), which satisfies the conditions, we have $\overset{\sim}{f}(n)\approx f(n)$ for large $n$.

Question 1: How to prove that $\overset{\sim}{f}(n)$ is asymptotical to $f(n)$?

Question 2: Let us consider a function $\overset{\sim}{a}(x)$ which satisfies an equation gained from substituting $a_n-a_{n-1}$ by $\overset{\sim}{a}'(n)$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r$ by $\int_0^n\overset{\sim}{a}(x)dx$ and so on in a recursive definition of a reel sequence $a_k$. Is there anything profound that can bed said of the relation between $\overset{\sim}{a}(n)$ and $a_n$?

Any help is highly appreciated!